# 10 Application pool limit question

Tags: web-application, service-application, application-pool, limitations

Does this limit include service apps as well? I'm currently sitting at 3 application pools for our web applications and 7 application pools for services.

Also, is it possible to change which application pool a service is using without recreating the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my information, App Pool Limit is only for Content Web Applications only(thats mean services app pool not counted towards limit) and This Count on WFEs. Usually Services app pools are on the Application server.

To change the App Pool you can do it via Central Admin.

- Go to Central Admin > Application Management
- Under Service Applications > Manage Service Applications
- Highlight, (don't click on the link) the service application you wish to modify
- Select Properties from the ribbon
- A nice silverlight popup window should appear, this is where you configure the service application's pool.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/511a64ea-3d7a-476b-b7e9-e2ba348acf9a/web-app-pools-vs-service-app-pools-in-iis?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: As an aside, the reason the limit doesn't apply to service apps is because you can specify exactly which servers each service runs on. The Web Application Service will load up every single content application pool you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

The advised maximum number of application pools is 10 and the maximum number of web applications is 20 as per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx

That said I would recommend the following:

a) use a single application pool for all services
b) use as few application pools as possible for content

In many cases, only 2 application pools (besides the standard ones that come installed with SharePoint) should be sufficient. Only in special cases (e.g. with strict security requirements) would you need additional application pools for service applications.